# nodelist index access returns undefined

Tags: javascript, dom, nodelist

i have this code:

```
const modelInputs = document.getElementsByName('jpd-model')
console.log(modelInputs)
```

it returns a NodeList of all the elements that match.

however this code returns `undefined`

```
const modelInputs = document.getElementsByName('jpd-model')
console.log(modelInputs[0])
```

according to how im reading the documentation it should allow me to access it because its array 'like'.

I would expect `console.log(modelInputs[0])` would output the first item of the nodelist *modelInputs*

here is a sample of html elements that have that name:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="jpd-model" id="jpd-model-1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" value="XXXX-900L-XXXX~(120,277)">
```

using latest brave browser on linux

updates:

1. added html element
2. i copied the wrong element the above one is correct.  I do have a make and a make-orig.  debugging output.

Comment: can you please share what the output is?

Comment: how does your element with name jpd-model look like?

Comment: the output is undefined

Comment: @Hafizallylalani i added the html element

Comment: I tried your code and it seems to work fine: https://codepen.io/michael-kaner/pen/LYZKLMb

Comment: Your input name is `jpd-make-orig`. Why are you accessing with `jpd-model`?

Comment: You cant access your dynamic data for the inputs with jpd-model

Comment: Try getting it by class name or so..

Comment: 1. the names don't match (`name="jpd-make-orig"` vs. `.getElementsByName('jpd-model')`, 2. `.getElementsByName()` will always return a `HTMLCollection` (not a `NodeList` - there's an important difference!), so the order of operations matters -> Add a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use "jpd-model" to get your list. This will fail because the name you use in your form is "jpd-make-orig"

You can easily achieve what you want by using a different selector getElementsByClassName for example.

Here is a working demo:

html:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="jpd-make-orig" id="jpd-make- 
orig-1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" value="LITHONIA" readonly="">
```

js:

```
 const modelInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('form-control')

 console.log(modelInputs[0])
```

https://codepen.io/michael-kaner/pen/LYZKLMb